# Executing batch file from php ba

Tags: php, shell

I have a batch file on my windows server .I want to execute it from php and print the result

i am using this php command

```
<?php
exec('/home/velvel/public_html/crawl/OpenWebSpiderCS/bin/OpenWebSpiderCS.exe        /home/velvel/public_html/crawl/OpenWebSpiderCS/bin/batch.bat',$output,$return);
echo $output;
echo $return;
?>
```

The return value is 126 and the output is just array,

I have searched over the internet and the 126 error code means the batch file is not getting executed or some permission problem.

Can any one help ?

Comment: You are executing `OpenWebSpiderCS.exe` with argument `batch.bat`. You are not **running** the BAT file. If you change to `exec("batch.bat", ...)`, then you would be actually running batch script.

Comment: I have tried with that, exec("batch.bat",$output,$return) it gives 127 error then. that means the exe to execute is not found or something

Comment: Any warnings, notifications?

Comment: it gives cannot execute binary files